# When will the 3rd edition of "Art of Electronics" by Horowitz and Hill finally be published?

Tags: books

Will the 3rd edition be published ?

Comment: Amazon has added it with June 2011 date of publishing http://www.amazon.com/Art-Electronics-Winfield-Hill/dp/0521809266 I wonder if anyone bought it yet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Next year is my guess. Win Hill has said that the problem with finalising the book is the pace of change in electronics, it's something of a moving target.

Comment: Amazon Canada (?) shows ISBN 0521809266 being dated March 2012. But still waiting for the sales to start.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this newspost](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/chat/the-art-of-electronics-3rd-edition-finished-writing-and-copy-editing/msg286789/#msg286789), the writing phase is completed and the book is now in typesetting, scheduled for a mid-2014 release.

**Update**
The book is scheduled to be released in [April 2015](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/physics/electronics-physicists/art-electronics-3rd-edition).

Comment: No more news on this?

Comment: Amazon is taking preorders: http://www.amazon.com/Art-Electronics-Paul-Horowitz/dp/0521809266/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1422454308&sr=8-1&keywords=art+of+electronics+3rd+edition